# On the existence of a signed measure related to the Hausdorff moment problem

Tags: measure-theory

This M.O [question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/138785/on-vanishing-signed-measure) reminded me of a problem I've seen a while ago and was not able to solve. Any reference about this kind of problem would be nice.

The problem is the following :

Does there exist a *signed* measure $\mu$ on $[0,1]$ such that
$$\int_{0}^{1} x^n d\mu = e^{-n^2}$$
for all $n \geq 1$?

Note that this is related to the so-called [Hausdorff moment problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_moment_problem), which however seems to deal only with positive measures.

It is quite easy to see that there is no *positive* measure satisfying the above, but does there exist a signed one?

Thank you,
Malik

Answer (score 1):

The case of a signed measure was studied by Hausdorff himself:

F. Hausdorff, Momentprobleme für ein endliches Intervall. Math. Ztschr. 16, 220-248 (1923).

http://www.digizeitschriften.de/dms/resolveppn/?PPN=GDZPPN002446111

The paper contains some conditions for this case, and you can try to check them.